# SQL code wont work for finding the least common value but the opposite (find the most common) will

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT `suburbcode`
  FROM PROPERTY
   HAVING count(*) <=
    ALL(SELECT count(*)
         FROM PROPERTY
        GROUP BY `suburbcode`)
```

I'm trying to find the value that occurs the least amount of times in a column. When I run this code, it returns no results, but when I do the opposite (`count(*) >= ALL`) it works and gives me the value that occurs the most times. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `group by`:

```
SELECT suburbcode
FROM PROPERTY
GROUP BY suburbcode
HAVING count(*) <= ALL (SELECT count(*)
                        FROM PROPERTY
                        GROUP BY `suburbcode`
                       );
```

If I were using this style, I would still be inclined to write:

```
SELECT suburbcode
FROM PROPERTY
GROUP BY suburbcode
HAVING count(*) <= (SELECT count(*)
                    FROM PROPERTY
                    GROUP BY `suburbcode`
                    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

The two versions do the same thing.